# Cordova : how to deploy windows 10 apps

Tags: windows, cordova, deployment

I built a `cordova windows 10 app`. The build works fine and I am able to launch my app on the simulator via `Visual Studio 2015`.

How can i deploy this app for an entreprise?
Basically I want to build an `appx` but I really don't know where to start?
And what are the different stages?

I developped and distributed many `cordova apps` on `iOS` and `Android` but the `windows` universe seems quiet dark...

Answer (score 3):

I have recently entered the dark world of deploying Cordova-based Window 10 apps for enterprise purposes.

Firstly, it makes a big difference if you are going to deploy via Windows Store or not. My answer below assumes you are going to use the standard public-facing Windows Store, but you can also go down the [private store via Windows Store For Business](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/itpro/windows/manage/distribute-apps-from-your-private-store) route to distribute enterpise apps, however I have no experience of this.

Unlike the Google Play Store for Android or App Store for iOS, Windows Store enables you to [deploy apps without publicly listing them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability#distribution-and-visibility). You can restrict access to Windows 10 apps to anyone in possession of the direct link or restrict access to a constrained list of people. The first option was good enough for me.

In order to upload the apps to the Windows Store, you need to generate a `.appxupload` bundle.

To do so with Cordova CLI I used `cordova build windows --release -- --archs="x86 x64 arm" --bundle --win`. You can also do this by opening the `platforms/windows/CordovaApp.sln` in Visual Studio and selecting "Project > Store > Create App Packages...".

Both of the above assume your app is already configured with the correct package name and certificate for the corresponding app profile. You can create a new app profile in the Windows Store developer portal: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/overview. The easiest way to associate a profile with the your Cordova project is via Visual Studio: "Project > Store > Associate App with the Store...".

You can then upload your `.appxupload` via the Windows Store developer portal when prompted to do so during the submission process.

For testing purposes, I used the [Sideloading mechanism](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/deploy/sideload-apps-in-windows-10), however this requires the device to be set in Sideloading or Developer mode, so is not suitable for enterprise deployment.

Comment: So there is no other solution than distribute via a windows store (private or public)

Comment: (wow the submitting the comment by the return touch is quiet disturbing)... So i was saying if I don't want to process via a windows store (private or public) and I just want to build an appx that will be installed on different devices how can I do that ? What type of certificate do I need ?

Comment: I've no experience of enterprise delivery outside of Windows Store, but AFAIK your only option is [Sideloading](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/deploy/sideload-apps-in-windows-10) but it's an ugly solution

Comment: OK I'll take a look. Basically, my client use sccm to deploy apps. I was thinking about building an appx and deliver it to them. My researchs learned me the client must provide a pfx file to let me compile the app.