# Cordova: is there some thorough documentation regarding app's building/deploying options (or flags) for Windows platform?

Tags: windows, cordova, build, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Searching for solution, how to build and deploy properly app for Windows 10 UAP, I've found @DaveAlden's answer in [Cordova: how to deploy windows 10 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39955733/7458546).

I've noticed there two flags used in build command: `--bundle --win` which I don't understand what they precisely are for and couldn't find in official Cordova documentation for Windows platform or in Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova.

This is the command I'm referring to:
`cordova build windows --release -- --archs="x86 x64 arm" --bundle --win`

I'd like to know, where are these flags are mentioned and in which docs if at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I've noticed there two flags used in build command: --bundle --win which I don't understand what they precisely are for and couldn't find in official Cordova documentation for Windows platform or in Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova.

`--bundle` indicate to create a bundle, please refer to [Create an app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool).

`--win` indicate you are currently target windows platform.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how do You know these flags were existent?
Where this is mentioned in docs?
Presence of bundle flag in MakeAppx.exe doesn't imply presence of same flag in cordova for windows.